# For each loop is Not Working in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

What i need :

- problem im facing im not data in key value pair.

here is my code

$metadata=json_decode($metadata,true);

it output me array

```
  Array
 (
   [name] => Yogender
   [email] => yogensingh@
    [designation] => Business Manager
    [website] => 
    [phone] => 91-92
    [company] => Veer Signages Pvt. Ltd.
    [city] => Gurgaon
[country] => India
 )
 Array
(
[name] => Prakash Tiwari
[email] => digital
[designation] => Director
[website] => 
[phone] => 91-981
[company] => Digital Semiconductors Pvt. Ltd
[city] => New Delhi
[country] => India
  )
```

- im fetching this array using foreach loop

  ```
  foreach($metadata as $key=>$value)

  {
    echo  $value['name'];

  }
  ```
- it output first string of array

  ```
   output    yB9VGI

       PdD9DNI
  ```
- i just want  to fetch   ['designation']  & ['company'] in key value pair.
  like

  ```
   [designation] => manager
    [company]=>google
  ```
- please tell me where im wrong any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: give a try to this: echo $value->name; and see what happens?

Comment: try $metadata['company'] and $metadata['designation'] also have you one array in $metadata one time or more arrays

Comment: no it does not ouput something

Comment: You seem to be iterating over the values in one of those sub-arrays, not all the arrays. Are you sure you're not doing `foreach ($metadata[0] as $key => $value)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i made this 
it working fine as below

```
 foreach($metadata as $key => $value) 
  {
    if ($key == 'designation' )
       $designation= $value;
    elseif($key == 'company')
         $company= $value;
```

}

echo "D=$designation and C= $company \n";

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you looking for:

```
foreach($metadata as $key => $value) {
 if ($key === 'designation' || $key === 'company')
  echo  $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($metadata as $value)

{
  echo  $value->name;

}
```

Comment: Why would leaving out `$key => ` make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if($k == 'designation' || $k == 'company')
    $newarr[][$k] = $v;
}
print_r($newarr);
```